# Create for loop to plot histograms for individual columns of DataFrame with Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

So I'm trying to plot histograms for all my continous variables in my DatFrame using a for loop I've already managed to do this for my categorical variables using countplot with the following code:

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes([np.object])

for i, col in enumerate(df1.columns):
    plt.figure(i)
    sns.countplot(x=col, data=df1)
```

Which I found here by searching SO.

However now I want to do the same with distplot so I tried modifying the above code to:

```
df1 = dftest.select_dtypes([np.int, np.float])

for i, col in enumerate(df1.columns):
    plt.figure(i)
    sns.distplot(df1)
```

But it just gived me one empty plot. Any ideas on what I can do?

edit: e.g of DataFrame:

```
dftest = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 5)),
                    columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sns.distplot` has been replaced by `sns.histplot`. See [Emulating deprecated seaborn distplots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67638591/7758804) to match `distplot`.

```py
for i, col in enumerate(df1.columns):
    plt.figure(i)
    sns.histplot(df1[col], stat='density', kde=True, kde_kws={"cut": 3})
```

---

It seems like you want to produce one figure with a `distplot` per column of the dataframe. Hence you need to specify the data in use for each specific figure.

As the [seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) says for `distplot(a, ...)`

> `a` : Series, 1d-array, or list. Observed data.

So in this case:

```
for i, col in enumerate(df1.columns):
    plt.figure(i)
    sns.distplot(df1[col])
```

Comment: What an easy fix! Thanks so much! now I just need to figure out what to do with my missing values and plot everything! All the best!

Comment: How can I achieve it in one big figure and have multiple small charts inside it? @mportanceOfBeingErnest

Answer (score 5):

Define a function to plot histograms

def histograms_plot(dataframe, features, rows, cols):

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
for i, feature in enumerate(features):
    ax=fig.add_subplot(rows,cols,i+1)
    dataframe[feature].hist(bins=20,ax=ax,facecolor='green')
    ax.set_title(feature+" Distribution",color='red')

fig.tight_layout()  
plt.show()
```

histograms_plot(df,df.columns,6,3)

Comment: Thanks. How do I scale the subplots so that the x axis is the same?