# Emulating deprecated seaborn distplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram, kernel-density

Seaborn [`distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) is now deprecated and will be removed in a future version. It is suggested to use [`histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) (or [`displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) as a figure-level plot) as an alternative. But the presets differ between `distplot` and `histplot`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

x_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 9, 9, 10]
df = pd.DataFrame({"X": x_list, "Y": range(len(x_list))})

f, (ax_dist, ax_hist) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)

sns.distplot(df["X"], ax=ax_dist)
ax_dist.set_title("old distplot")
sns.histplot(data=df, x="X", ax=ax_hist)
ax_hist.set_title("new histplot")

plt.show()
```

[image]

So, how do we have to configure `histplot` to replicate the output of the deprecated `distplot`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I spent some time on this, I thought I share this so that others can easily adapt this approach:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

x_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 9, 9, 10]
df = pd.DataFrame({"X": x_list, "Y": range(len(x_list))})

f, (ax_dist, ax_hist) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)

sns.distplot(df["X"], ax=ax_dist)
ax_dist.set_title("old distplot")
_, FD_bins = np.histogram(x_list, bins="fd")
bin_nr = min(len(FD_bins)-1, 50)
sns.histplot(data=df, x="X", ax=ax_hist, bins=bin_nr, stat="density", alpha=0.4, kde=True, kde_kws={"cut": 3})
ax_hist.set_title("new histplot")

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

The main changes are

- `bins=bin_nr` - determine the histogram bins using the [Freedman
  Diaconis Estimator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram_bin_edges.html#numpy.histogram_bin_edges) and restrict the upper limit to 50
- `stat="density"` - show density instead of count in the histogram
- `alpha=0.4` - for the same transparency
- `kde=True` - add a kernel density plot
- `kde_kws={"cut": 3}` - extend the kernel density plot beyond the histogram limits

Regarding the bin estimation with `bins="fd"`, I am not sure that this is indeed the method used by `distplot`. Comments and corrections are more than welcome.

I removed `**{"linewidth": 0}` because `distplot` has, as pointed out by @mwaskom in a comment, an `edgecolor` line around the histogram bars that can be set by matplotlib to the default `facecolor`. So, you have to sort this out according to your style preferences.

Comment: You could also add `alpha=0.4` to the `histplot`

Comment: Well spotted. I had the impression that the color is slightly off but didn't follow through with this thought.

Comment: "Regarding the bin estimation with bins="fd", I am not sure that this is indeed the method used by distplot. Comments and corrections are more than welcome." This is basically correct; `histplot` uses numpy's `"auto"` mode, which takes the max of the FD and Sturges estimators. The only thing that will be tricky to fully replicate is that `distplot` used `min(FD_bins, 50)` by default. So if you really want *exactly* the same behavior, you'll need to do that externally.

Comment: Oh also `linewidth=0` is wrong; `distplot` bars have visible edges, but with the matplotlib defaults the bar edgecolor is set to `"face"`. You'll see the difference if you activate one of the seaborn themes.

Comment: @mwaskom Thanks for your input, I was hoping for your comments. I assumed that `auto` was the preset for distplot because the documentation mentions something about an optimized approach. However, this was obviously wrong. Not sure though, how to implement the different edgecolor settings but I guess people can figure this out based on their specific stylesheets.

Comment: @Mr.T `distplot` uses *an* "optimized" approach (relative to a fixed number of bins), but there are lots of different reference rules that work better or worse for different sorts of data ... numpy's `"auto"` tries to balance the two of the most common ones. Actually when `distplot` was written, numpy didn't have any of the reference rules implemented, so `distplot` implements the FD rule internally. It became possible to pass `bins="auto"` once numpy added it and matplotlib hooked into numpy for computation, but the default remained to use the internal FD computation, with the upper limit.

Answer (score 0):

**#Use histplot()
#histplot is used on univariate**

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = sns.FacetGrid(data = data, col = 'variable name', hue = 'variable name', heigth = 9, palette = 'Set1')

fig = fig.map(sns.histplot, variable name, kde = True).add_legend()
```