# Problems with color coding while changing deprecated sns.distplot to sns.histplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I`m want to replace the deprecated sns.distplot with the "new" sns.histplot for the viszualization of a prediction vs measured - quality target with two overlapping histograms.
"old way"

```
x1 = y_predict
y1 = y_test_asarray
figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.xlabel('Air perm.')
plt.title('Air perm. measured vs. predicted')
sns.distplot(x1 , 60,  color='red', label='pred')
sns.distplot(y1 , 60,  color='Blue', label='measured')
plt.legend()
```

showing this:

[image]

changing the code to the sns.histplot works, but the color argument isn`t executed. I`m not able to get the color-coding working, so both histogramms are the same color. Any recomendations to get the recoloring working?

```
x1 = y_predict
y1 = y_test_asarray
figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.xlabel('Air perm.')
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
plt.title('Air perm. measured vs. predicted')
sns.histplot(x1 , bins=60,  color='red', kde=True, label='pred')
sns.histplot(y1 , bins=60,  color='Blue', kde=True, label='measured')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: See also [Emulating deprecated seaborn distplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638590/emulating-deprecated-seaborn-distplots)

Comment: Are you using seaborn 0.11.1?  Your problem doesn't seem to be reproducible.  You can also create the plot in one go, setting the labels via a dictionary. In that case the bin boundaries would be shared.  E.g. `sns.histplot({'pred': np.random.randn(200), 'measured': np.random.randn(500)}, bins=60, palette=['red', 'blue'], kde=True, stat='density')`

Comment: Yes I`m using 0.11.1. While looking at the array in your code, i think i have found the error reason. My array is created from a time-series dataframe (timespan is the index), so i think therefore the array is 2-dim and causing this. array is like array([[341.5 ],
       [323.96],
       [162.97],
       ...,
       [354.83],
       [179.51],
       [236.49]])

Comment: You could use `sns.histplot(np.ravel(x1) , bins=60,  color='red', ....)` to make the input 1D.  The index normally will be ignored for the histogram.  Note that your y-label is wrong. The y-values of the default `histplot` are the counts of each bin. With a discrete domain and individual bins, you could show a probability. With a continuous distribution, you could show a probability density.

Answer (score 1):

np.ravel and the dictonary-creating works out pretty well, thanks for the held!

```
x1 = np.ravel(y_predict)
y1 = np.ravel(y_test_asarray)
figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.xlabel('Air perm.')
plt.title('Air perm. measured vs. predicted')
sns.histplot({'pred': x1, 'measured': y1}, bins=60, palette=['red', 'blue'], 
kde=True, stat='density')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XqjK.png)

Answer (score 0):

@JohanC astutely diagnosed the problem with the dimensionality of your arrays, but while updating your code, why not take advantage of the features that make `histplot` better than `distplot`?

```
predicted = np.random.randn(400, 1)
actual = np.random.randn(400, 1)
data = {"pred": predicted.squeeze(), "measured": actual.squeeze()}
ax = sns.histplot(data, bins=60, kde=True)
ax.set(xlabel="Air perm.")
ax.figure.set_size_inches(10, 10)
```

[image]