# FutureWarning: `distplot` is a deprecated function and will be removed in a future version

Tags: python, seaborn

I used sns.distplot, but it is a deprecated function.
Is there any good alternative that have 'fit'?

```
sns.distplot(y, kde=False, fit=stats.norm)
```

Right now I'm using this

```
s1, loc2, scale2 = lognorm.fit(y)
r2 = lognorm.rvs(s1, loc2, scale2, size=r_size)
sns.histplot(data=r2, kde='True', ax=axes[1], alpha = 0)
sns.histplot(data=y, ax=axes[1])
axes[1].set_title('Log Normal')
```

[image]

Comment: You have to [emulate the old distplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67638591/8881141) but you came up with this solution yourself.

Comment: It was 1 string of code against 5 now. Maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: The creator of seaborn (@mwaskom) commented under the linked thread. If there was a simple substitute, he would have mentioned it, I assume.