# what to use instead of sns.distplot?

Tags: python, data-visualization

I am working on a data set of House Pricing - Advanced Regression .
To Visualize my data after some cleaning I used `sns.distplot()` but its showing "FutureWarning: `distplot` is a deprecated function and will be removed in a future version."
Here is code when I used `distplot()`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


num_var = ['MSSubClass', 'LotArea', 'OverallQual', 'OverallCond',
       'YearBuilt', 'YearRemodAdd', 'MasVnrArea', 'BsmtFinSF1', 'BsmtFinSF2',
       'BsmtUnfSF', 'TotalBsmtSF', '1stFlrSF', '2ndFlrSF', 'LowQualFinSF',
       'GrLivArea', 'BsmtFullBath', 'BsmtHalfBath', 'FullBath', 'HalfBath',
       'BedroomAbvGr', 'KitchenAbvGr', 'TotRmsAbvGrd', 'Fireplaces',
       'GarageYrBlt', 'GarageCars', 'GarageArea', 'WoodDeckSF', 'OpenPorchSF',
       'EnclosedPorch', '3SsnPorch', 'ScreenPorch', 'PoolArea', 'MiscVal',
       'MoSold', 'YrSold', 'SalePrice']

plt.figure(figsize=(25,25))
for i,var in enumerate(num_var):
    plt.subplot(9,4,i+1)
    sns.distplot(df[var],bins=20)
    sns.distplot(df3_drop_rows[var],bins=20)


#num_var = columns of my data
#df = Original data
#df3_drop_rows = Data After cleaning ( Simple cleaning just droped some rows and columns )
```

I got this output
[image]

So then I tried to use `displot()` instead of `distplot()` after going through documentation and some stack overflow Answers then I changed my code to this

```
num_var = ['MSSubClass', 'LotArea', 'OverallQual', 'OverallCond',
       'YearBuilt', 'YearRemodAdd', 'MasVnrArea', 'BsmtFinSF1', 'BsmtFinSF2',
       'BsmtUnfSF', 'TotalBsmtSF', '1stFlrSF', '2ndFlrSF', 'LowQualFinSF',
       'GrLivArea', 'BsmtFullBath', 'BsmtHalfBath', 'FullBath', 'HalfBath',
       'BedroomAbvGr', 'KitchenAbvGr', 'TotRmsAbvGrd', 'Fireplaces',
       'GarageYrBlt', 'GarageCars', 'GarageArea', 'WoodDeckSF', 'OpenPorchSF',
       'EnclosedPorch', '3SsnPorch', 'ScreenPorch', 'PoolArea', 'MiscVal',
       'MoSold', 'YrSold', 'SalePrice']

plt.figure(figsize=(25,25))
for i,var in enumerate(num_var):
    plt.subplot(9,4,i+1)
    sns.displot(data=df[var],kde=True)
    sns.displot(data=df3_drop_rows[var],kde=True)
```

I got this output after doing some correction
[image]

But my Issue is , I want output like first image i.e I want to plot both of my original data and cleaned data in one graph and all 36 graphs in ( 9 rows , 4 columns ) format.

Comment: You have mainly two options. One is to downgrade your seaborn to a previous version. The other is to [emulate the internal procedures of the old distplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67638590/8881141).

Comment: You need `sns.histplot(...., kde=True)` as a more close replacement of `distplot`.  Note that `displot()` is a figure-level function, meant to create a complete grid in one go (but you'd need a "long form" dataframe). As a figure-level function, `sns.displot` creates its own new figure, ignoring the figure created with `plt.figure()`